# Visual Studio 2010, SharePoint 2010, External webparts

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am trying to create a share point web part in VS2010 and every time I create a new project it spazzes out and states it cannot create the project as their is no share point server on my machine, well duh - its hosted else where.

in Visual studio 2010, when creating a new share point project is there a way to say, the share point server is at this web address?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible, as its a development requirement to have all the SharePoint dlls to be present in your local machine which will not be there without installing SharePoint.

One work around is explained in the below link,
http://techblog.hk.agenda-asia.com/2010/10/29/create-sharepoint-project-without-install-sharepoint-server/

but I suggest you going for a VM with SharePoint for development which will be less cumbersome.